# Set-InternetProxy not working on Windows 10

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set the system proxy using PowerShell, so I found the PowerShell script from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-function-Get-cba2abf5

I ran it as they mentioned in the comment section

```
.\Set-InternetProxy.ps1 -proxy "5.187.52.68:5836"
```

It ran but no error or any output printed. Then I try to check my IP using the browser but it's showing me the actual IP so the proxy is not set.

I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is not accepting parameters directly, script has a function named Set-InternetProxy, so you should load the script to memory first using the below command

. .\Set-InternetProxy.ps1

and then call the function

Set-InternetProxy -Proxy "5.187.52.68:5836"

OR

You can delete line numbers 18, 19 and 74, save the script and run as you are doing now
You may also have to run Unblock-File -Path .\Set-InternetProxy.ps1